# ATK4: Error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: atk4

I am defining a method in ATK4 with an expression field in it:

```
$this->addExpression('answered')->set(function($model,$select){
    return $select->dsql()
          ->table('answer')
          ->field($select->expr('if(count(*)>0,"Y","") as answered'))
          ->where('usecollection_id',$select->getField('id'))
          ->where('student_id',$this->api->auth->get('id'));

  })->type('boolean')->caption('Besvaret');
```

It works fine on my development machine, but on the production server it throws a fatal error: PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in file.php

This is the problematic line:

```
$this->api->auth->get('id')
```

Any idea what causes this difference and how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to pass $this to enclosed function like this:

```
$self = $this;
$this->addExpression('answered')->set(function($model,$select)use($self){
    echo $self->api->auth->get('id');
});
```

That's how you should pass variables quite often to anonymous functions in PHP.

Another possibility in this particular case is to simply use `$select->api->...`, `$model->api->...` or any other ATK4 object instead of `this->api->...`. That's because all ATK4 objects have reference to API class, so `$whateverObject->api->...` will always work and always point to same API class object.

Comment: It worked fine just to change $this to $select. So simple. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh see, told you there was a better way :) Thanks DarkSide!

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a variable ($this) that is not passed nor declared within the function (you're passing $model and $select to the function).

I'm not smart enough to tell you the best way to fix this, maybe you can define $auth_id (set it to $this->api->auth->get('id')) before the function is called and pass that variable to it as well?

There is bound to be a better way though...